# GoogleSheets =VLOOKUP, =SUM

Tags: google-sheets, gs-vlookup

I am trying to copy some information from another sheet and sum them with different multipliers. This code roughly works:

```
=VLOOKUP(D8,Market!A:K,11,FALSE)+VLOOKUP(E8,Market!A:K,11,FALSE)*2+VLOOKUP(F8,Market!A:K,11,FALSE)*3+VLOOKUP(G8,Market!A:K,11,FALSE)
```

I am sure there must be a shorter way to do this - what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not shorter but an alternative approach might be:

`=MMULT({1,2,3,1},{VLOOKUP(D8,Market!A:K,11,0);VLOOKUP(E8,Market!A:K,11,0);VLOOKUP(F8,Market!A:K,11,0);VLOOKUP(G8,Market!A:K,11,0)})`